# ElasticSearch import issue

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a client for ES in SCALA [ school project ] . 
but when I want to import Elastic search I got some problems

I've written a sbt file :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch" % "1.4.2"
 libraryDependencies += "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-core" % "4.10.2"
```

with other lucene

and when I try to use it :

```
import org.elasticsearch.node.Nodebuilder.*
object Setup {
  Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
  Client client = node.client();
}
```

it does recognize     `org.elasticsearch.node.`     but not     `.Nodebuilder.`

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: It's complaining about the `*`. In scala, you use the underscore `_` for wildcard imports. e.g.: `import org.elasticsearch.node.Nodebuilder._`

Comment: There is no need to import lucene-core, elasticsearch does the import for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder
val node = nodeBuilder().node()
val client = node.client()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the following library: https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s